# Overwrite static member by using another file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting a js project to typeScript and I want to overwrite some constants static members by using a local/untracked_by_git file.

My original constants file:

```
export default class Constants{
    static MYSQL_HOST = 'some_host';
    static MYSQL_PORT = 0000;
    static MYSQL_DATABASE = 'prod_database_name';
    static MYSQL_USER = 'user';
    static MYSQL_PWD = 'password';
}
```

**I want a local file (untracked by versioning system) that is able to overwrite any of this fields (in order to connect to some particular db, different than my collegues)**

Comment: is this code for browser or server ?

Comment: Why you could not use just environment variables?

Comment: @qballer it is for server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following the advice from [@mario-alexandro-santini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6452829/mario-alexandro-santini)

```
export default class Constants{
    static MYSQL_HOST = process.env.MYSQL_HOST || 'some_host';
    static MYSQL_PORT = process.env.MYSQL_PORT 0000;
    static MYSQL_DATABASE = process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE || 'prod_database_name';
    static MYSQL_USER = process.env.MYSQL_USER || 'user';
    static MYSQL_PWD = process.env.MYSQL_PWD || 'password';
}
```

assuming you are running in a UNIX based environment you can have a bash file lets call it `set-env.sh`. add that file name to the `.gitignore` file and it should contain something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSQL_HOST="Other values"
MYSQL_PORT="LOL"
MYSQL_DATABASE="LAlaLA"
//etc..
```

when you run the app just do something like `./set-env.sh && <the command you did before>`